# Function not returning value due to errors in if else logic

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on a little script to extract the file names from the given absolute paths which can be Win and linux. The script is supposed to grab the file where the paths are stored, one per line, and extract the filename with pathlib. However pathlib has a problem where the path ends with a slash - / or \ .
I have a function 'remove_slash' which supposed to recursively remove all the trailing slashes.

- First weird problem is that it always enters the else block which I
  believe is caused by EOL symbol
- Second, when the path is clear of trailing slashes it enters the 'if'
  vlock and supposed to return the formatted path but it does not. Im
  pulling my hair off trying to figure out why there is no value
  returned.

If someone experienced could take a look and point me in the right direction.

There is a  bunch of print's for debug purposes, discard.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pathlib import Path,PurePath
import sys

# Function which removes trailing slash
# if there is no slash at the end - return path
# else run this function with the slice
def remove_slash(path):
    print(f"Entering with : {path}")
    if path[-1].isalnum():
        print(f"iffffff {path[-1].isalnum()}::::{path[-1]} ::: {path}")
        return path   # **THIS NEVER GETS RETURNED**
    else:
        print(f"else : {path}")
        remove_slash(path[:len(path)-1])

if len(sys.argv) ==1 or len(sys.argv)>2:
    print(f"Usage : {sys.argv[0]} filename") 
    sys.exit(1)

File = sys.argv[1]

with open(File) as F:
    for path_line in F:
        print("==========================")
        print(f"path before : {path_line}")
        path_line = path_line.replace('\\','/')

        path_line = remove_slash(path_line)
        print(f"path after : {path_line}")
        p = PurePath(str(path_line))
        print(f"part  : {p.name}")
        #p.parts
print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
print(remove_slash('//home//python//projects//files.py////'))

#print(f"+++++++++++++++++++ {str(qqq)}")
```

Comment: Trailing slashes are removed automatically `pathlib.Path('//home//python//projects//files.py////')` -> `PosixPath('//home/python/projects/files.py')`.

Comment: "Remove all the trailing slashes" can be done with simply `path.rstrip("\\/")`.  Your function is failing because you are throwing away the return value from any recursive call.

Comment: Just a note: instead of `path[:len(path)-1]`, just use `path[:-1]`.

Comment: @jasonharper I need to be able to remove /, \, //, \\ and any other variation. But you were right I havent returned any value from recursion.

Comment: That is *exactly* what the code I posted will do.

Comment: @jasonharper, tried it and in fact it does remove all of the trailing slashes. Many thanks.

Comment: @Daniel your solution will not remove Windows slashes when on Linux/MacOS

Comment: @yoK0: sure, because `\\` is a valid character in unix file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `remove_slash` is recursive, and your recursion calls return nothing. So somewhere down the recursion stack, the correct string is returned, but the next level up does not return anything, so `None` is the actual return. Just add a return in your `else` block:

```
def remove_slash(path):
    print(f"Entering with : {path}")
    if path[-1].isalnum():
        print(f"iffffff {path[-1].isalnum()}::::{path[-1]} ::: {path}")
        return path   # **THIS NEVER GETS RETURNED**
    else:
        print(f"else : {path}")
        return remove_slash(path[:len(path)-1])
```

Comment: Silly me. Thank you.